# Build getting failed due to firebase sdk dependency

Tags: java, firebase, maven, spring-boot, dropwizard

I have created pom.ml file as mentioned below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>friendr-core</groupId>
    <artifactId>friendr-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>friendr-core</name>
    <url>http://www.google.com/</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <dropwizard.version>1.0.4</dropwizard.version>
        <testng.version>6.1.1</testng.version>
        <jersey-entity-filtering-version>2.23.1</jersey-entity-filtering-version>
        <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
        <spring-framework.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <c3p0-version>0.9.1.2</c3p0-version>
        <mysql-connector-java-version>6.0.5</mysql-connector-java-version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.apache.httpcomponents-version>4.3.1</org.apache.httpcomponents-version>
        <jbcrypt-version>0.3m</jbcrypt-version>
        <testng-version>6.9.10</testng-version>
        <java-mail.version>1.4.5</java-mail.version>
        <velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin-version>2.2</maven-shade-plugin-version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smoketurner</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.httpcomponents-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bcrypt : Hashing library used for password -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>${jbcrypt-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.httpcomponents-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jdbi</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-java-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Email dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>${velocity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>${java-mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.friendr.core.application.CoreApplication</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

Now it is working fine there is no issue but when I am trying to add below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auto.value/auto-value -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
    <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And executed command `mvn clean package` then build was failed and getting below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.2:shade (default) on project friendr-core: Error creating shaded jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature) -> [Help 1]
```

Please help me to add these dependency in my existing pom.xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like either the `firebase-admin` or `auto-value` (or both) are corrupt. There are at least two ways to fix that if that is the problem

### Change version

Both packages have newer versions available

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auto.value/auto-value -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
    <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will make maven download a new version of those libraries, which should be fine unless there's a reason you really have to use the versions you specified in the question. Try running `mvn clean package` again

### Delete locally cached libraries

Maven stores (caches) copies of dependencies. By default they are stored in

- Windows: `C:\Users\{your-username}\.m2\repository`
- Linux/Mac: `~/.m2/repository`

Delete the cached versions of both libraries by deleting the following folders `~/.m2/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-admin/6.8.0` and `~/.m2/repository/com/google/auto/value/auto-value/1.4.1` (or similar for Windows)

Then try to run `mvn clean package` again

Comment: Updated suggested version and removed cache now working fine, thanks for the help